# In SML, does every variable denotes a reference?

Tags: programming-languages, sml, ml

In C ,

- every variable denotes a reference, and we can get the reference from a variable by operator `&`. e.g. if `int x=1`, then `&x` is the reference denoted by   variable `x`.
- every variable is evaluated to the value referred to the reference. e.g. `x` is evaluated to `1`.

In SML,

- does every variable denotes a reference?  E.g. If `val y = ref(3)`, then `y` denotes a reference which refers to `3`. if `let val x = 4`, what does `x` denote: `4` or a reference which refers to `4`? Can we get the reference denoted by variable `x`, similarly to `&` in C?
- `y` is evaluated to reference `ref 3`, and `x` is evaluated to `4`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A variable binding in SML does not introduce a reference. You cannot get a reference to the `x` in your example. All references have to be created explicitly, and are first-class values. And only such references are mutable, bindings are not.

In other words, bindings and references are completely independent features in SML.